# Asynchronously schedule sequential processes with the multiprocessing.Pool Python class

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I'm running simulations using an executable in parallel with the Python `multiprocessing.Pool` class as follows:

```
self._pool = Pool()

return self._pool.apply_async(run_executable, [],
    dict(simulator=self,
    params=params,
    command=self._command,
    results=self._results))
```

Let's say we want to run 5 simulations on a computer with 4 CPUs, then (if I understand correctly) the processes get scheduled as follows:

[image: Multiprocessing with 5 processes and 4 CPUs]

The problem arises when I need the results of a previous simulation to start a new simulation with adjusted parameters. If we use the same figure as before and let simulation `i.j+1` follow on simulation `i.j`, the scheduling should look as follows for the easy case where we have a number of simulations equal to the number of CPUs:

[image: Multiprocessing with follow up]

How can I wait for the right process to finish, do the post-processing and then start a new simulation again in asynchronous mode? (I don't really care if this gets done by the same CPU, I just want to use the maximum amount of CPU power available).

Comment: Does `apply_async` return a promise? You can add a callback to the promise which will be executed once the promise is resolved.

Comment: It returns a `result` object yes: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html which has a function `wait()`but I think this induces the GIL

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this and have a look what it does.

```
self._pool = Pool()

def process_ended_callback(result):
    print(self._command, "resulted in", result)

return self._pool.apply_async(run_executable, [],
    dict(simulator=self,
    params=params,
    command=self._command,
    results=self._results), 
    process_ended_callback)
```

It should print which command just ended.

Comment: The print statement works indeed but what I need is for the callback function to do the post-processing and restart the simulation. However, the documentation clearly states the callback function should immediatly return a value...

Comment: Can you put the post-processing in another thread or process and use the callback function to start that?

Comment: Yes that is possible. The result of a simulation is written to a file which is read by the post-processing to initialize the new simulation so information is easily shared between processes.